# Is it possible to read class files from a jarfiles from a certain path

Tags: java

So I am fairly new to java but what I am trying to achieve is I have a list containing jar files that are in a certain directory and I want to be able to read the class files inside those jars and then globally search a string that would be inside a class file.

My current code:

```
public class Dank 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<File> jarFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] mods = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods").listFiles();


        for(File file : mods)
        {
            if(file.isFile())
            {
                String filename = file.getName();
                if(filename.endsWith(".jar")) {
                    jarFiles.add(file);
                //  System.out.println(filename);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you mess with that if McForge itself provides ways to get mod(classes)? Besides what are you looking for? Specific classes, or data inside a class file? Since the later is a whole lot more stuff

Comment: I want to be able to search a string in every class files and if that string happen to exist then a certain event happens

Comment: There is specification on `class` file format. One of section of `class` file contains all strings used in it.

Comment: Where would the String be located? Variable name, method name, documentation(why???). Or  would an annotation be a solution as well? Since it would save a lot of messy stuff

Comment: variable name is what i am trying to get

Comment: The strings that you are looking for inside those class files are reachable via class's fully qualified name (e.g. `foo.Bar.staticVariableName`), right? Then you should _load_ the classes using Java.

Comment: In 16 years of Java development I've never had to read a class file. What is it you want to do? See: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: this problem relates to Minecraft (modding), which loads mods contained in .jar/.zip files. That is why the OP needs some kind of classLoading, unless he/she uses McForge itself which implemented plenty of ways to acces fields/methods from other mods safely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking for a variable with a specific name you can use the following:

```
Class<?> clazz; //get the class you need
Field f = clazz.getField("Variable_name");
// if Field f is null, no field exist with the given name

// this is necessary if the field is not public.
f.setAccessible(flag);

// if the field is not static, the parameter is the instance you want the field from
// otherwise it can be null
Object variableValue = f.get(null); // or f.get(clazzInstance);
```

This doesn't require special classloading or class file readers/parsers. Besides it can be done at any moment without too much performance loss.

Though as a disclaimer, this does take more time than directly reffering a field directly. Especially because you have acces to McForge, you can use the different subclasses of `Optional` as well, which might be an even better solution for this problem. It is decently documented, so I suspect it wouldn't be too difficult to get a grasp on.

Hope this pointed you in the right direction, Note that this post actually belongs on the [ForgeForums](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php?board=73.0), as it can easily be solved with the McForge's system.

Comment: A statement like `doesn't require special classloading` should be treated with care. If the jar files are not located in the classpath on application startup (and the directory the OP pointed to is with some certainty not in it), you need some way to get the class object inside the jar file. Without custom classloading this might be hard to achieve. Also, if you don't need the class files any further in your application it might be wasteful keeping them in memory. Unloading of classes with the app classloader, however, is not yet possible.

Comment: I do understand that it could be the case in an application. But knowing the Minecraft modding enviroment, I dare to state such comment, as everything is preloaded (and there is even a relaunch) before any (event)methods are called in your own mod. From personal experiance I can tell it is actually really difficult use a classLoader within that enviroment because of the preloading, ASM and the relaunch. As an extra I would state that this problem is actually off topic as the problem can be solved with the help of the McForge implementation, and therefore should be posted on the ForgeForums